# How to change the back button color on md and ws in Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I was able to set the back button icon and remove the text using app config but how can I set the color for the icon? Ios picks up the primary/secondary color but it shows up as black in Android and Windows.

```
imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
  'backButtonText':'',
  'backButtonIcon':'arrow-back',
  'pageTransition':'ios'

},{}
)]
```

[image: Difference between the back button colors in ios, md and ws]

Answer (score 2):

You need to give it as shown below on your **component's** `.scss` file.

```
.ws,
.md {
  .back-button {
            color: red;//what ever the color you like
        }
}
```

If you need to do it **globally** then You have to do it as shown below.

**Note:** I don't like to use `!important` hack.But unfortunately, it's not working without that.

***app.scss***

```
.md,
.wp {
    .back-button {
        color: red !important;//what ever the color you like
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that should work. When you say globally you mean in app.scss ?
I was hoping for some documentation by ionic around this.

Comment: Yes, you have to define it inside the  `app.scss`.I have mentioned it on above post too.

Comment: There is no doc about this.This is just a `CSS` hack.But if you need to learn about `Ionic2 theming` then: http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/